# parse xml document with javascript in wamp server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to web development and right now I am facing a problem with parse xml document in javascript in wamp server. I understand that both web page and XML file it tries to load, must be located on the same server.  So I put both php and xml files into the same folder within the www folder, but it didn't work. Does it mean that localhost can't be treat as a server and how can it parse the xml document within the javascript?
Thank you very much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>W3Schools Internal Note</h1>
<div>
<b>To:</b> <span id="to"></span><br>
<b>From:</b> <span id="from"></span><br>
<b>Message:</b> <span id="message"></span>
</div>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","note.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("from").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("from")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

below is my xml file

```
<!--  Edited by XMLSpy®  -->
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: I set the parameter of xmlhttp.open() to false,but still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have modified a very important part of this script: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp , the 3rd parameter of `xmlhttp.open`has to be set to `false` to make it work, but in your script it is set to `true`

With the 3rd parameter set to `true` the request will run asynchronously, you must wait until the readystate of the request is `4` before you may access the complete response.

Working example with `async` set to `true` : http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_first